# Is there a way to host a webServer in perl which should in HTTPS

Tags: perl, https, webserver, cgi, web-hosting

I am setting/updating a web server using `Perl(Net::Server::HTTP)` which was running in http. I would like to convert into Https mode. I would like to know what modules will solve my purpose.

Comment: It's in the description section of the Net::Server::HTTP documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As simbabque already mentioned, check out the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Server::HTTP) for the module.

It lists the following example:

> For example, here is a basic server that will bind to all interfaces, will speak both HTTP on port 8080 as well as HTTPS on 8443, and will speak both IPv4, as well as IPv6 if it is available.
>
> ```
> use base qw(Net::Server::HTTP);
>
> __PACKAGE__->run(
>     port  => [8080, "8443/ssl"],
>     ipv   => '*', # IPv6 if available
>     SSL_key_file  => '/my/key',
>     SSL_cert_file => '/my/cert',
> );
> ```

The most significant thing to note is in `port` it's an array ref that contains the http port (8000) and then the https (ssl) port (8443/ssl).

Comment: Thanks, @Dave, I have configured the certificate as suggested. I am facing a cipher suite mismatch issue. I would like to know if any compatibility/configuration issues are causing this. **Could not finalize SSL connection with client handle (SSL accept attempt failed because of handshake problems)**. -> SERVER-side Error
**This site can’t provide a secure connection (site name) that uses an unsupported protocol.ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH Unsupported protocol. The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.** -> Browser-side Error

Comment: @Dheerajkumarreddy: You're talking to the wrong person. This isn't my answer. I just cleaned up the code example.

Comment: Oh, I missed it completely.  I should have marked @Bl00D4NGEL in the comment.